# How to add where condition to grouping aggregation query in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

Currently, my query statement in Apache IoTDB is like this: `select count(status), max_value(temperature) from root.ln.wf01.wt01 group by ([2017-11-01 00:00:00, 2017-11-01 10:00:00), 4h, 2h)`. Can a `where` condition be added to this grouping aggregation query in IoTDB? Any example that I can refer to?

Answer (score 0):

Conditional filtering can be added to `group by` query in Apache IoTDB, for example to add `where value›0` before aggregation. Or longer command like `where time>=XXXX and time<=xxxx Group by ([date1time1,date2time2),1d) fill(0) align by device` is also supported.